# transferring userId from one component to another using vue router

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a list of users obtained from the api. I need to make sure that when you click on the user's name, a page with his information opens with a separate link

Component UsersList

```
<button @click="showUserPage(user.id)">Go to the user's page</button>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    users: [] 
  }
}
```

```
showUserPage(userId) {
  // Navigation to user details
  this.$router.push({ name: 'user-page', params: { userId: userId } })
}
```

```
fetchUsers() {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
      .then(response => {
        this.users = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading users', error);
      });
```

Component UserPage

```
data(){
    return{
      user: {}, 
 
    }
  },
methods:{
  getUser(userId) {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?userId=${userId}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.user = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error loading users', error);
        });
  }
```

```
created() {
  this.getUser(this.$route.params.userId)
```

router.js

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: UserList },
    { path: '/user/:userId',name:'user-page', component: UserPage }
]
```

after clicking on the button, a link with the correct id appears (like 'http://localhost:8080/#/user/8').But if I'm trying to display user information `{{user.name}}` I'm getting an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined'.After trying to console.log(this.$route.params.userId) i get error "cannot read properties of null (reading '$route')
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.user` is set in `getUser()` so it is undefined, until `getUser()` is called. Maybe set it to a mocked value to see if that is displayed and then think about when to call `getUser()`

Comment: if you mean passing the id to a separate variable, then I've already tried and get error "cannot read properties of null (reading '$route')"

Comment: No that's not what i mean; I thought that your error is not what you think (because the passing of `userId` seems to be correct). You could try to pass it as query parameter (google that) just to test a different way.

But first: can you make sure which variable is undefined
is it `this.$route`?  or `this.$route.params`? or `this.$route.params.userId` or is it `this.user` (as i am expecting)
Therefore add a console.log(this.$route) and so on to created() on the user page and check the log in your browser dev utils.

And if i am right setting `user: {'name': 'unknown'}`, will fix it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your template is attempting to render the `user` object before it has a chance to get a response from your API.

You may need to surround your `{{ user.xx }}` calls with a `v-if` to prevent Vue from trying to render it.

Something like this:

```
<div v-if="user">
    Hello, {{ user.firstName }}
</div>
```

To get real fancy, you could add some sort of loading indicator for your users.

Something like this:

```
<script>

    ...
    data() {
        return { 
            userIsLoading: false,
            user: undefined,
        }
    } 
    methods: {
        getUser(userId) {
            this.userIsLoading = true;

            axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?userId=${userId}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.user = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error loading users', error);
        });
        
        this.userIsLoading = false;
    }

    ...
}
</script>
```

Then in your template you could do something like this:

```
<div v-if="userIsLoading">
    Getting user info...
</div>

<div v-if="!userIsLoading && user">
    Hello, {{ user.firstName }}
</div>
```